# Repeated values with same array in different Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a regular English but I will try my best.

I have a Object called Student with name and array of notes.

In Main program I fill name and random notes in each Student. Then I show the values.

The problem is to fill notes array from Object, I use a auxiliar array called notes, I fill this array and put it in notes property of Student, but when I show the values all students have the same notes values. If I clean the array it's works well, but I want to understand why this happens.

Student Class:

```java
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public int[] notes;
}
```

Main Code:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student students[] = new Student[5];
        int notes[] = new int[5];
        Random random = new Random();
        //Fill values.
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            students[i] = new Student();
            students[i].name = "Name" + i;
            for (int j = 0; j < notes.length; j++) {
                notes[j] = random.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;
            }
            students[i].notes = notes;
            //notes = new int[5]; //Need start array to get right values.
        }

        //Show values.
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Student: " + students[i].name);
            for (int j = 0; j < students[i].notes.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Note" + j + ": " + students[i].notes[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing the same array instance into each Student object. For this to work, you need to pass a new array for *each* Student object.

Comment: e.g., create a `new int[5]` ***inside*** of the for loop, so that a new array object is created with each iteration.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, when I use array1 = array2, array1 has the reference of array2, not the values. I read this site and explains all ways to do:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-copy-in-java/